# Compare two dicts and print non-equal values in python

Tags: python, dictionary, key, inequality

I need to compare dictionary b against a to check whether the keys of b are in a.

If present check the values of `a[key]==b[key]`. If not equal print the `key:value` pair of both dictionaries for reference. How can I do that?

```
a = {'key_1': 1,'key_2': 2, 'key_3': 3}
b = {'key_1': 1,'key_2': 5}

[k for key in b if key in a if b[k]!=a[k]]
```

I used the above code, but not able to print both the dictionaries keys and value as like

```
not equal: b[key_2]=5 and a[key_2]=2
```

Answer (score 2):

*I need to compare dictionary b against a to check whether the keys of b are in a.* You want to find the *intersecting* keys and then check their values:

```
a = {'key_1': 1,'key_2': 2, 'key_3': 3}
b = {'key_1': 1,'key_2': 5}

# find keys common to both
inter = a.keys() & b 
diff_vals = [(k, a[k], b[k]) for k in inter if a[k] != b[k]]
# find keys common to both
inter = a.keys() & b

for k,av, bv in diff_vals:
    print("key = {}, val_a = {}, val_b = {}".format(k, av, bv))
key = key_2, val_a = 2, val_b = 5
```

You can use many different set methods on the dict_view objetcs:

```
# find key/value pairings that are unique to either dict
symmetric = a.items() ^ b.items()
{('key_2', 2), ('key_2', 5), ('key_3', 3)}


# key/values in b that are not in a    
difference = b.items() - a.items()
{('key_2', 5)}

# key/values in a that are not in b
difference = a.items() - b.items()
{('key_3', 3), ('key_2', 2)}

# get unique set of all keys from a and b
union = a.keys() | b
{'key_1', 'key_2', 'key_3'}

# get keys common to both dicts
inter = a.keys() & b
{'key_1', 'key_2'}
```

Comment: This appears to be python3 code, correct? Because, for python2, i had to wrap most parts into `Set()` constructions

Comment: @helt, just use `viewitems()` and `viewkeys()` for python2.  That returns what you get in python3 just using `items()` and `keys()`.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is likely this:

```py
result = [(k, a[k], b[k]) for k in a if k in b and a[k]!=b[k]]
```

In other words, "generate a list of tuples composed of the key, the first value and the second, whenever a key in a is also in b and the corresponding values are not equal".

Since the boolean expressions with "and" are failsafe (they evaluate from left to right and stop as soon as a False value is found), you don't have to worry that "b[k]!=a[k]" could raise an exception.

This raises another question: what if the key is in a and not b or vice-versa, e.g. ('car', 2, None) or ('car', None, 2)? Should that also be a valid answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a small error in the code you posted. First, you seem to mix `k` and `key` for the same object. Second, you cannot have two `if`-clauses in a list comprehension, but instead you can combine them with `and`. Here is how it could look: `[k for k in b if k in a and a[k]!=b[k]]` 
This will produce a list with all the keys for which the values don't match. Given such a key, you can simply use e.g. `"a[{k}]={a} and b[{k}]={b}".format(k=k,a=a[k],b=b[k])` to get a human-readable string describing that mismatch. Of couse, if you are only going to create that list of keys to loop over it afterwards (for printing), then there is no need to actually create that list in the first place. Simply iterate directly over the dictionary keys.

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
a = {'key_1': 1,'key_2': 2, 'key_3': 3}
b = {'key_1': 1,'key_2': 5}
i=[k for k in b if k in a if b[k]!=a[k]]
if i:
    for k in i:
        print('not equal:b[',k,']=',b[k],'and a[',k,']=',a[k])
```

Output

```
not equal:b[ key_2 ]= 5 and a[ key_2 ]= 2
```